# microservices: How to model related domain objects?

Tags: microservices

I have 2 domain objects: Project and Contract.  A project can have many contracts so in the database it is modeled as a classic one-to-many relationship.  Our question is this: How do you model the above in the context of microservices?  Do you (a) have 2 microservices ProjectService and ContractService?  or (b) Do you have one ProjectService which encompasses both Projects and Contracts?

We are thinking that answer (a) (i.e. 2 microservices ProjectService and ContractService) implies that one would have to call 2 services to retrieve and save the complete Project object hierarchy.  On the other hand, answer (a) completely decouples Projects from Contracts which may be a good thing in theory, but practically useless since a Contract cannot logically exist without a Project.

What is the correct approach here? Is answer (a) an example of the nano service anti pattern?

Comment: OK, why the down vote?  Is this question not useful? Does it not show research effort?  What is the problem?

Comment: It's a great question. One I had as well. A big shame, the SE Programmers  closed it. I guess they're trying to make it a weaker brother of SO... :(

Comment: Why was it closed? This is a very practical question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've looked at the nano services anti-pattern and indeed in my opinion option (a) is an example of it.

**But also, you need to consider that your domain logic here, dictates the "Project-Contracts" coupling(it's by definition) therefore the finest(smallest) granularity of the microservice should include the whole thing(Project-Contracts coupling).**

**Suggestion:**
*I'd go for option (b) with the following twist, **but only if you think that handling the Contracts alone requires too much code:*** consider having it as a private service class (not exposed to the outside world) that should only be constructed by a parameterised constructor which takes the ProjectID(or similar) as its parameter.